# Saving outputs (some lines in a file)

Tags: bash

I use this command:

./nodetool status

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                                      Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  47.66 KB   1       33.3%   aaa1b7c1-6049-4a08-    ad3e-3697a0e30e10  rack1
UN  127.0.0.2  47.67 KB   1       33.3%   1848c369-4306-4874-afdf-5c1e95b8732e  rack1
```

How can i do to redirect some outputs into a file ? I'd like save only these details in a file:

```
  UN  127.0.0.1
  UN  127.0.0.2
```

Then, i'd like to add to the file the timing:

```
  10:15:00  UN  127.0.0.1
  10:15:01  UN  127.0.0.2
```

I have used 
[image]
Thanks a lot for all ideas.

Kind regards.

Comment: `Cut` is your friend, and `echo`.

Comment: @djsmiley2k Please why i can't display date1 in the file test2.txt ?
awk '{print $date1, $1,$2}' test1.txt > test2.txt

Comment: Does $date1 have a value?

Comment: @djsmiley2k  date1=$(date +"%s")

Comment: @djsmiley2k myvar=$(date +"%T")
awk -v var="$myvar" '{ print var,$1,$2 }' test1.txt > test2.txt   RESOLVED. Bests.

Comment: As you've figured it out, now put that as an answer and you can even accept it yourself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -ne '6,/END/ p' test.txt > test1.txt
myvar=$(date +"%T")
awk -v var="$myvar" '{ print var,$1,$2 }' test1.txt >> test2.txt
```